# If I have three points on a circle, how do I calculate other points on the same circle?

Tags: geometry

I have circle which I know intersects the x axis at -11.5 and 11.5.  It intersects the Y axis at 1.  How can I calculate the (positive) Y value for any X value between -11.5 and 11.5?

This is to calculate an arc for a carpentry project.  the arc is too shallow to use the usual mechanical techniques for finding the radius.

Comment: Seen [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcircle.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Since the intersection with the $x$ axis are symmetrical with respect to $0$, it is easy to prove that the centre lies on the $y$ axis.

Let $(0,a)$ be the centre. Then the equation is

$$x^2+(y-a)^2=R^2 (*)\,.$$

$$11.5^2+a^2=R^2=(1-a)^2 \,.$$

This Yields:

$$11.5^2=1-2a$$

You can find $a$ from here, get $R$ from $R^2=11.5^2+a^2$ and then get your equation $(*)$.

Comment: or simply $R = 1+a$

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you very much.